# Issue turning leased IP /24 Block into a reverse proxy

Tags: proxy, reverse-proxy, squid, bgp

Objective: I want to create a forward proxy server that when I connected from my machine to it, I can use any of the leased IPs I have leased outbound.

The long story....I leased a /24 IP block from IPXO and have assigned it to the private ASN of my Vultr instance (I also have my own ASN as well if that is needed, but used the vultr one as its a feature built into their platform). I enabled BGP and used BIRD in a Ubuntu Linux instance within VULTR (following the multiple tutorials and guides) and setup Squid (not married to this solution if there is something better that does the job, I am more than happy to try). When I try to use the proxy, it doesn't seem to allow to use the leased IPs outbound. It still shows the Proxy server internal IP. I did update the config file for Squid to allow outbound to one of the IPs from the Block that I leased. There has to be something I am missing or something I am not setting it. Sadly I have looked around and I have failed to find documentation that go through this process end to end. Eventually I would like the server to operate as a SOCK5 proxy server. But first I just want something to work.

Any help or advice is sincerely appriciated.

Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Comment: The asn.1 tag is incorrect here. asn.1 refers to Abstract Syntax Notation 1 (ITU-T X.680) and not autonomous system number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are general steps for troubleshooting to consider:

1. Ensure subnet has valid ROA, IRR (WHOIS) route object
2. Ensure subnet is visible on the Internet and is not hijacked. This can be verified via https://stat.ripe.net/app/use-cases/prefix/routing-check/
3. Ensure that IP address that your are using for SQUID proxy are configured on your server's interface. If there is no firewall, you should be able to ping it from your computer
4. Ensure that SQUID actually uses your configured IP address by running tcpdump on your server and capturing outgoing packets

For your specific situation, there seem to be issues with the first two points. If you intend to announce on the VULTR ASN, you need to assign VULTR ASN to your subnet via IPXO. You can contact IPXO support to help you resolve this issue.

Sincerely,

IPXO Team

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. Will check on that and report back.